# Структура БД комплектующих

Tags: ms-access

Стоит задача: создать список комплектующих (блоки питания, материнские платы, оперативная память, видеокарты и т.д).
Функции для БД следующие: необходимо добавлять новые комплектующие, изменять имеющиеся комплектующие, отчеты и выборки.
При этом требование следующие: Необходимо иметь связи между таблицами, и они должны быть по смыслу. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как можно организовать структуру БД, чтобы было удобно создавать отчеты, выборки и т.д?

Я сначала подумал, что может будет удобнее раскидать каждый тип комплектующего по таблице, например таблица "Материнские платы" где у нее в полях описан производитель, название, характеристики со стоимостью, и так со всеми остальными видами, но в этом случае связывать нечего..

Comment: Советов, основанных на мнениях, вы тут не получите. Здесь помогают найти решения, основанные на фактах.

Comment: Но лично от меня совет. - используйте Excel. Не нужны никакие базы данных. Если нужен складской учет, используйте любую программу инвентаризации, уже всё есть... зачем придумывать что-то новое. Сейчас в 2021 году уже понятия материнских плат, процессоров, оперативной памяти, видеокарты очень размыты. Во многих компьютерах всё перечисленное может быть одним устройством.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, многие интернет-магазины и обзорные сайты держат всю информацию по компьютерным комплектующим в одной широкой таблице со множеством колонок. Этих комплектующих заведомо немного: сотни, ну тысячи позиций. У них несколько десятков свойств (колонок), в большинстве из которых null. Ни одна СУБД не подавится таким мизерным объёмом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не могу с вами согласиться, вот есть хороший пример [linux-hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/) Все структурировано и совместимости все прописаны. Я нашел [свой старый комп](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=3ee6b79682#Logs) по материнской плате и клавиатуре.

Comment: @DiD К сожалению, я делаю по учебе мини-диплом по Access'у, и у меня жесткое требование сделать список комплектующих, и я уже неделю сижу пытаюсь придумать структуру данных..

Comment: @Hitomizavr Если бы вы знали... каждый год одно и тоже... Технологии меняются , а списки тем к дипломным работам остаются. Одну и ту же работу выполняют тысячи людей каждый год))

Comment: @Hitomizavr  Вот держите, готовый вариант всего что вам нужно. https://github.com/MokshaSri/database  . А если хоть на русском языке научитесь гуглить - и пояснительную запуску к этой БД найдете.

Comment: @DiD А вас не смущает что у этой БД в гите стоит пароль? И да, первым делом я загуглил тему которая мне нужна, но увы, того что мне нужно я не нашел, нашел только платные готовые дипломные работы.. Но все равно спасибо за попытку помочь

Comment: @DiD - структурировано где? На морде сайта, на фронтенде? А что на бекенде? Известно, какая у них СУБД и как она организована? Ведь данные для отображения в GUI могут браться откуда угодно, хоть из плоских текстовых файлов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Они используют БД informix. На сайт выкладывают только заранее генерированные статичные страницы.

Comment: @Hitomizavr Извиняюсь, к сожалению я не мог удостовериться в том, что та БД - это то, что вы ищете, так как к сожалению, у меня нет установленной Access в виду её дороговизны и несовместимой с ней операционной системы. Но я нашел как минимум еще три похожих проекта на github менее чем за минуту поиска. А если я в гугле начну искать...